# Calling Web APIs on NetBeans for Java

Tags: java, api, netbeans

How do I send queries and receive information from Web APIs to use for my Java application?

API CALL example: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID={APIKEY}

Comment: Perform a GET request to URL. Deserialize the results from that call into Java objects. Do stuff with the Java objects.

Comment: @TomMac What if I needed a key to access the API. I.e: The API Query is made through a webform?